# How do I perform full text search in man pages?

Tags: manpage

I'm aware about `apropos/man -k`, but they search in summaries, while I need to search entire man pages.

How can I do full text searches in man pages?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To search within the text of your manual pages, and not just their headings, use `man -K`. You can search for simple search strings (e.g. `man -K "example text"`), or use the `--regex` option to use regular expressions in your search.
It will give you the first matching manual page; press `q` to close it and you will be presented with the option of reading the next match (`Enter`), skipping the next match (`Ctrl-D`), or quitting altogether (`Ctrl-C`).