# Command to search through manuals?

Tags: command-line, search

Can't remember it. Tried to google it with no luck. I encountered it last week but the browsing history is wiped.

Here's what that command does. You just write it in terminal with some word. It will search through all the manuals from repository and print out the list of matches with short description.

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about, but in case that helps here's a trick I use to search (say) an option of a command on its man page: `man <command> | grep -A 10 '<escaped_option>'`, where `<escaped_option>` is e.g. `\-a`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I perform full text search in man pages?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/116112/how-do-i-perform-full-text-search-in-man-pages)

Comment: Also see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/20752/how-can-i-search-within-a-manpage and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195571/how-to-search-the-whole-manual-pages-on-linux and many (many) more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for `apropos` or `man -k`.

From `man man`:

```
man -k printf
           Search the short descriptions and manual page names for the 
keyword printf as regular expression.  Print out any matches.  
Equivalent to apropos -r printf.
```

From `man apropos`:

```
apropos - search the manual page names and descriptions
```

Check `man apropos` and `man man` for details.

Comment: @seeker_of_bacon Happy to help  :)