# Searching for Commands

Tags: command-line, manpage, helpfile

I am new here, so thanks for accepting me.

Ok, so I have a really dum question, sorry, I am presently still learning.

So what if, I had no idea of what commands are available for a specific task or process, where would I look, ?? I mean say I did not know any commands, I wanted to find all the commands that might be appropriate for a specific task or process, how can I find these ??

All of my studying so far just covers the Man or Help commands, so that assumes I already know the command, but what if I don't, ??

For a simple example, if I wanted to Cut and Paste a file, is there anywhere I could type in 'Cut and Paste' and that would give me answers like mv, cp, rm, I could then look up using Help or Man, ??

I hope this makes sense, please forgive me, if not.

Kind regards and thanks in advance

Comment: The `man` command takes `-k` which uses the word after as a keyword search.  i.e., see `man man` for an explanation.  But I personally turn to Google if I am not looking for a command, but some kind of description of a task, with either "ubuntu" or "linux" as a search term.  Yeah...so, I use Google.  Not sure what others would use.

Comment: See [Command to search through manuals?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/634830/command-to-search-through-manuals) (although it likely won't help in this specific case, since "cut and paste" is a GUI concept that has no direct analogy in the CLI)

Answer (score 2):

The command `apropos` allows to find the name of commands related to a certain keyword.

For example, the command

```
apropos directory
```

will give a list of commands related to directory manipulation, along with a short one-line description of what the command does. Once you located a command of interest, you can learn how it works with man. e.g , the command above includes an entry

```
mkdir (2)            - create a directory
```

so if that was what you wanted to do, you can learn about the command with

```
man mkdir
```

The command `man -k directory` would be fully equivalent to the `apropos` command presented above. If you think `whatis` is easier to remember than `apropos` (with its French flavour), you can use that.